# Prolog example for forward and backward chaining

Tags: prolog

As per the rule of inst., any security person who allows
any outsider to enter the campus without any valid ID-proof will be
suspended. Some outsiders without any valid ID-proofs are found inside
the campus. All these outsiders were allowed to enter the campus by a
security person named Mr. X.

```
(a) From the above statements, construct a knowledge base.
(b) Implement forward and backward chaining.
(c) Using the forward chaining and backward chaining, prove that
“Mr. X must be suspended”.
(d) Compare the efficiency of forward chaining and backward chain-
ing algorithms with respect to the number of irrelevant clauses
generated.
```

For the above question I approach like this.

```
securityPerson(mrx).
outsider(P).
securityAllows(mrx,P).
suspended(Z) :- securityPerson(Z),outsider(P),securityAllows(Z,P).
```

Query:

```
?- suspended(mrx).
true.
?- suspended(mrxa).
false.
?- trace.
true.
[trace]  ?- suspended(mrx).
Call: (7) suspended(mrx) ? creep
Call: (8) securityPerson(mrx) ? creep
Exit: (8) securityPerson(mrx) ? creep
Call: (8) outsider(_G1937) ? creep
Exit: (8) outsider(_G1937) ? creep
Call: (8) securityAllows(mrx, _G1938) ? creep
Exit: (8) securityAllows(mrx, _G1938) ? creep
Exit: (7) suspended(mrx) ? creep
true.
```

Is it correct?If not please help

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: You should read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

No it is does not seem to be correct. You have not coded `inside campus.' Also, your rules seem to imply that Mr X is an outsider. You should make up some individuals instead of having a(n implicitly universally quantified) variable in the outsider/1 clause.